# Can't regex string between string and line break - str(x) versus x.decode()

Tags: python, regex

Why does a regex fail of a string cast from an object when line breaks are present?

That is why does this fail to find a match (ie print 'Green') in a string created from str(obj):

```
import re
s = str(b'Package Name: Green\\r\\n Release version: 8.1\\r\\n')
match = re.search(r'Package Name: (.*)\r\n', s)
print(match.group(1))
```

When this succeeds using a string created from obj.decode()?

```
import re
s = (b'Package Name: Green\\r\\n Release version: 8.1\\r\\n').decode()
match = re.search(r'Package Name: (.*)\r\n', s)
print(match.group(1))
```

No matter what search pattern was tried, searching the string created by str(obj) failed to find a match...

Comment: These both fail with a `SyntaxError`. Please give us a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Most importantly, what type is the actually thing you're calling `str(…)` or `….decode()` on? Also, which Python version are you on?

Comment: At any rate: In Python 2.x, `str` calls `encode` when given a `unicode` object, and does nothing when given a `str`. In 3.x, `str` calls `repr` when given a `bytes` object, and does nothing when given a `str`. It never calls `decode()`. So why would you expect the same results that you get from `decode`?

Comment: And if you still don't get the issue: Try `print(b'abc\r\ndef\r\n')` in Python 3. There's no carriage returns or newlines in it, just backslashes and r and n letters. So of course you can't match newlines that don't exist.

Comment: As it says in the description:  it's an object.  What's shown for the object is an example -  you can't just copy it and run it in the console.  The object that I'm working with is a lot larger than what's shown.  And it's Python 3.6.  How about upvoting now?  Jeez...@abarnert your second response was at least somewhat helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: “an object” isn’t very helpful. Everything is an object. Meanwhile, there’s no `decode` protocol that means something across types. The  only builtin types that have such a method are bytes and bytearray, and neither one does the same thing as str. So I have no idea why you expect this other object, whatever it is, to do the same thing for these two cases. And if you won’t explain that, you don’t have an answerable question.

Comment: It's a 'bytes' object.  Sorry - I should have shown that in the question in the first place.  Question updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get different results is that you’re doing different things. Calling `str` on a bytes with newline characters returns a string with a literal backslash and `n`; calling `decode` returns a string with a newline character in it. So, if you’re searching the results for newline characters, the second one will succeed, and the first will fail. And it’s the second one that you wanted.

In other words, using `decode` here is right, and `str` is wrong; that’s why you get different results. If you can’t think through the difference, try just printing them out: `print(b.decode()); print(str(b))` and you’ll see the difference immediately.

In fact, you should usually be decoding the strings as soon as you receive them, and never looking at the bytes again. Then you never have to worry about the str representation of bytes objects (except maybe in some code that logs errors caused by invalid strings that you couldn’t decode). The only exception is when you know the bytes are some kind of encoded text, but can’t be sure what the encoding is. For example, if you’re parsing HTTP headers or email messages or Python source code, you don’t know the character set until you read part of the file and search it for special ASCII-encoded strings. Or, if you’re converting a bunch of old text files from Windows to Unix line endings and some are cp1252 while others are cp1250, you don’t care which is which because they both encode line endings the same way. For those cases, just stick with `bytes`, and search for `b'\n'` instead of `'\n'`.

---

If you want to know why Python makes this so complicated:

`bytes` objects are used to store strings encoded in your default encoding—but they’re also used to store strings encoded in different encodings, and binary data that isn’t a string at all. And a `bytes` object has no idea which of those it’s storing; they’re all just sequences of numbers.

Python 2 effectively assumed that a `bytes` was being used to store a string in your default encoding, so it let you convert back and forth to Unicode by calling functions like `str`, or even concatenating a bytes and Unicode string. That turned out to be one of the biggest sources of errors in the language. You still see Python 2 users posting questions here every few days asking why they got a `UnicodeEncodeError` when they weren’t calling `encode` anywhere (or, worse, when they were calling `decode`), and fixing that was one of the main reasons for Python 3’s existence.

The human-readable representation of a `bytes` object has to be something that can be produced without error, and read unambiguously, whether it’s a string in the default encoding, a string in a completely different encoding, or a sequence of pixel brightness values ranging from 0 to 255. The compromise solution (for things like that HTTP headers case above) is the backslash-escaped quoted string.

By the way, during the Python 2 to 3 transition, the core devs assumed multiple people would come up with clever `EncodedBytes` types that carried around their encoding, and could therefore act more like Python 2 byte strings but without all the associated errors, and after a couple years one of them would be the clear winner on PyPI and maybe they could add it to Python 3.3 or so. That’s what you’re probably instinctively reaching for here. But, as it turned out, nobody used any such libraries, because it’s almost always easier to just decode and encode at the edges of your program and use Unicode everywhere, and the exceptions are almost always cases where you don’t know the encoding so `EncodedBytes` wouldn’t help.

---

One last thing: thinking of functions like `str` or `float` as “casts” is misleading. While it looks superficially similar to the way you do explicit casts in C or Java or Go or whatever language you’re used to, it has a very different meaning